# Radio button Issue in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have some radio button pairs of same groupName.  If I set one radio button to checked = True , as a result, the view is not displayed.  I'm writing the code in aspx.cs but view is not updated.  For other controls its get updated.

```
chatSettingsNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ToolBarChatSettings/ChatSettings/AdminSettings/Emoticons");
valueChk = chatSettingsNode.InnerXml; 
value = Convert.ToBoolean(valueChk);
if (value == true)
{
    rbtnAdminEmoticonsYes.Checked = true;
}
else
{
    rbtnAdminEmoticonsNo.Checked = false;
}
chatAdminSettingsNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ToolBarChatSettings/ChatSettings/AdminSettings/AllowGroupChats");
//If the value Equals true or false Assigned to radiobox
valueChk = chatAdminSettingsNode.InnerXml;
value = Convert.ToBoolean(valueChk);                                            
if (value == true)
{
    rbtnAllowGroupChatsYes.Checked = true;
}
else
{
    rbtnAllowGroupChatsNo.Checked = false;
}
```

ASPX

"/>
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                            " GroupName="rbtngrpEmoticons" />
                                            " GroupName="rbtngrpEmoticons" />

Answer (score 0):

try

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

for radiobutton.

Comment: But I'm getting the Correct value from xml.but its not updating.

Comment: if you add html code to your question, we can check this. I think the problem is about clientside.

Answer (score 0):

In the markup for the radiobutton or the init code, You need to set

```
AutoPostBack = "true"
```

But you also need to refresh whatever container the radio button is in.

```
upPanel.Update();
```